# NODE_ENV not getting passed from ECS Fargate to React Application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

I have a React application that was built using Create-React-App. I have set up a deployment pipeline using GitHub Actions so that when I commit to branch 'pre-production' it will trigger a Docker Build and then put the build to AWS.

**Here is part of the GitHub Actions .yml:**

```
  - name: Build and push image to Amazon ECR
    id: build-image
    env:
      ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
      ECR_REPOSITORY: application
      IMAGE_TAG: latest

    run: |
      # Build a docker container and
      # push it to ECR so that it can
      # be deployed to ECS.
      docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
      docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
      echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

Then inside my ECS Service, I have my task running which points to this build, and inside that container, I pass in the environement variables, like below:

[image]

I then console log out the NODE_ENV in the application which for some reason keeps saying **production** instead of **development**.

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

Comment: Where have you put this value as production before? It seems like something is overriding that

Comment: something like a hardcoded env in the Dockerfile with higher priority or something? Cause generally speaking your way of accessing the env var is correct.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I haven't set it to production anywhere, I am thinking 'npm run build' sets it to production for me? But I am not sure.

Comment: @Marc There is this line in the Dockerfile but I not sure this has anything to do with it `ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH` other than that there is no mention of `ENV`

Comment: sorry. Cant help you there then.

Comment: Are you using `webpack`? If yes, is `mode` set to `production`?

Answer (score 0):

check if environment variable is hard-coded somewhere, also worth trying with a different environment variable value to validate.

Comment: This isn't hardcoded anywhere and also trying it with a different variable wouldn't make a difference as this current one doesn't even work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure all the node documentation says you can't modify NODE_ENV in any way, especially the way you are attempting to do it, it's only able to be set by the build process